# Recover media from Android backup files

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, external-sd, data-recovery, 7.0-nougat

first time I ask a question here so I'll try to explain myself at my best. English is not my native language, so please bear with me.

In 2017 I had an Asus Zenfone 2 that got bricked plus it doesn't charge anymore, pc doesn't even detect it, usb port is broken I think, nor enters in recovery mode.
Lucky me, when it started having problems 2 years ago, I entered recovery mode and did a backup on an sd card from the RM menu.
Now I found the backup files and I thought it would be nice to recover my old pictures.
Shame is that I don't have the slightest idea on how to use these files.

[image]

These are the backup files. In the folder "abba" there are four more folders containing several 1KB files.
Does anyone know if I can still recover something and how to do it?
I thought maybe by using an Android Virtual Machine but I wouldn't know how to do it...

At the time I think my Asus mounted Nougat, don't know if it can be a useful information.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a compressed TWRP backup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/207257/how-to-extract-a-compressed-twrp-backup)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems that `data/media` contains nothing so I must have reset the phone before the backup (it seems odd to me because I'd never do something so unlogical).
Anyway, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

TWRP allows backup for devices with no external MicroSD Card. Therefore TWRP does always exclude Internal Storage from backup. They recommend manually copy Internal Storage via USB-MTP (which makes sense after creating  TWRP backup because it contains TWRP Backup folder too). If you know how to unpack/repack recovery.img you can add this fix (experimental) https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3941108 this will allow you backup of Internal Storage from TWRP

Comment: Question is not about how to enable SD card backup in TWRP, the actual concern is how to extract SD card data from an already created backup. Which is not possible because `/data/media/0` isn't backed up, whether TWRP had the capability to do so or not.

Comment: true. but the question can not be answered without any existing backup of /data/media/0 or explanation why it never exist. so this is answer how to create such backup, instead of wondering how to recover